# Book about boy who mistakes glue for treacle

Tags: story-identification, books, childrens-novel

I remember reading a book when I was younger, and I loved it. I've been trying to find it for ages, and have had no luck.

From what I remember, the cover is possibly blue. It is about a boy who is always getting into trouble and having misadventures. He mistakes glue for treacle, and overflows the washing machine, over adventures.

Not much information to go off, I know. But any help would be great! Thanks.

Comment: Does this book have science fiction or fantasy elements?

Comment: His name is I.E., and he loves glue (http://www.zaphinath.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/ie-eats-glue.jpg)

Comment: Apologies, I was the one who pushed this on reopen queue because my eyes had imagined a checkmark near the answer (which is SFFnal), but they were obviously tricking me. Don't mind me, vote to leave closed, time for me to go to bed.

Answer (score 5):

### This could be *[Merry Mister Meddle](http://www.enidblytonsociety.co.uk/book-details.php?id=2166)*

[image]

In one story, "Meddle Does the Washing," Mr. Meddle's use of a growth spell causes the washing-tub to overflow:

> "I'll go to Dame Know-all and ask her for a little growing-spell,"
>   thought Meddle. "I'll pop it into the wash-tub with the lather, and it
>   will grow marvellously so that I can do all the washing in no time at
>   all."
>
> He went off to Dame Know-all. She was out. Meddle looked round her
>   little shop. Ah—there on a shelf was a bottle marked
>   "Growing-spells." Just what he wanted! He put sixpence down on the
>   counter, took down the bottle, unscrewed the lid and emptied a small
>   growing-spell into his hand. It was like a tiny blue pea.

Of course, the tub overflows, since he had taken a much too strong growth spell:

> The lather fell out of the tub and went on growing. Soon Meddle was
>   waist-deep in bubbles! He kicked at them.

In another story, "Meddle's Treacle Pudding," Mr. Meddle mistakes glue for treacle:

> "My goodness me, if it isn't treacle!" he said."Look at that now! A
>   pot full of melting treacle, and Aunt Jemima hasn't any at all."He
>   stirred it. It wasn't treacle, of course, it was glue. But that didn't
>   enter Meddle's head at all. He was sure it was good rich treacle. He
>   stirred it well.
>
> "This would taste lovely on our pudding," he thought. "It's just what
>   we want. I wonder if the workmen would mind if I had two big spoonfuls
>   for our pudding. I'll ask them."